# JMeter Thread Communication Pre and Post Process delay

Tags: performance, timer, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

My Test Plan have 3 Scenarios,

1. Submit Quote
2. Check Status
3. If Status Complete get Quote Details.

If I keep all these 3 scenarios in one thread then CTT is not putting constant throughput, when I remove create 2 thread 1 for Submit and other for Status and Get Details I am able to maintain CTT, but my 2nd and 3rd Scenario volume drops almost 50%. As I have dependency on 1st step I am using Thread communication and not sure how I can either get CTT in one thread or get same volume from 2 different threads.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Constant Throughput Timer is useful to shape the load where there is > 1 test iteration. If your thread group has only one iteration consider using [Throughput Shaping Timer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) instead or play with ramp-up and thread number values. It is recommended to have only one instance of the CTT in your Test Plan as it's rather resource consuming by nature.

- If your scenario assumes different throughput for different thread groups you can add a CTT per Thread Group (make sure that you select `All active threads in current thread group (shared)` in "Calculate Throughput based on" dropdown
- If ITC test elements are throttling your test below desired throughput value consider using

  - [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty)
  - [__property()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property)
  - [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum)

  functions to implement inter-thread communication instead. JMeter Properties are global, can be accessed from different thread groups and persist all the time while JMeter is running.

See [How to use JMeter's Throughput Constant Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) for details.

If above information is not enough try to elaborate your query and include i.e. thread numbers, target throughput and what kind of information needs to be shared across thread groups.